# How do I get Process ID from HWND using managed VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a managed VB.net way to get the Process ID from the HWND rather than using this Windows API call.

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
              ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer

Sub GetProcessID()

    'start the application
    Dim xlApp As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'get the window handle
    Dim xlHWND As Integer = xlApp.hwnd

    'this will have the process ID after call to GetWindowThreadProcessId
    Dim ProcIdXL As Integer = 0

    'get the process ID
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlHWND, ProcIdXL)

    'get the process
    Dim xproc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcIdXL)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't wrapped by .NET. But there's absolutely nothing wrong with calling the native API functions. That's what the framework does internally, and that's why P/Invoke was invented, to make it as simple as possible for you to do this yourself. I'm not really sure why you're seeking to avoid it.

Of course, I would recommend using the new-style declaration, which is the more idiomatic way of doing things in .NET (rather than the old VB 6 way):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Your other option, if you absolutely cannot get over the irrational compulsion to stay with managed code, is to make use of the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. This can be used to start an external process, and has a property ([`Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx)) that can be used to retrieve the process's ID. I'm not sure if that will work for you. You specifically avoid telling us why you're using `CreateObject` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I have no hesitation to use Windows API when needed, but I do find it more cumbersome to use. I am happy to continue using Windows API for this.

Comment: I changed DllImport to System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport then it worked fine.

Comment: Ah yes, that has to either be a `Imports` statement at the top of your code file, or qualified on each use. I keep all of my API function declarations in a separate file containing a module called `NativeMethods`, as recommended by many style guides.